# Post JSON con Arry sin Quitar "\" de un Arraylist Android Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, retrofit

Tengo que imprimir un `JSON` con un `ArrayList` para hacer un request, al momento que meto los datos a `body` me manda con unas "" y con \ que evitan que pueda hacer el request de manera correcto, por ejemplo

> {"obj":{"Id":0},"Lst":[{"Clv_x":12334,"idy":1}]}

si mando eso en el body me regresa respuesta, pero android manda al body esto

> {"obj":{"Id":0},"Lst":"[{\"Clv_x\":12334,\"idy\":1}]"}

como puedo hacer para quitar esas "" y \ extra que tengo

Anexo parte del codigo:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("Id",0 );
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject1.put("obj",jsonObject);
    /////Hasta aqui guarde el primer JSON////////
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject2.put("Clv_x", 12334);
    jsonObject2.put("idy", 1);
    ////Aqui guarde el 2 JSON que va dentro del ArrayList////
    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayLists = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayLists.add(jsonObject2);
    //////Guardo JSON dentro del Array///////
    JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject3.put("obj", jsonObject);
    jsonObject3.put("Lst", arrayLists.toString());
    ///Creo el JSON que contiene el primer JSON y el ArrayList
    MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charse=utf-8");
    final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, String.valueOf(jsonObject3));
    ///Aqui posteo en el body el JSON //////
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando `JSONArray()`:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("Id",0 );
JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject1.put("obj",jsonObject);
/////Hasta aqui guarde el primer JSON////////
JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject2.put("Clv_x", 12334);
jsonObject2.put("idy", 1);

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);

//////Guardo JSON dentro del Array///////
JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();
jsonObject3.put("obj", jsonObject);

jsonObject3.put("Lst", jsonArray);

///Creo el JSON que contiene el primer JSON y el ArrayList
MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charse=utf-8");
final RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, String.valueOf(jsonObject3));
```

Al hacer `JSONObject.put` el mismo verificará si el argumento es primitivo, `JSONObject` o `JSONArray` para realizar la serialización, para los demás objetos como ser las Colecciones lo serializará como String.

Comment: Si es asi, muchas gracias! :D